# Count all from rows

Tags: php, mysql

Is possible to count some value from rows in mysql and write it in PHP?

Example:

```
 Username     Damage  
|------------|------------|  
|  user123   |     325    |  
|  user356   |     6634   |  
|  user426   |     422    |  
|  user993   |     92     |   
|  user183   |     4235   |
```

How I need to have all damage in one, example in PHP: `<? echo "$alldamage"; ?>`
But I don't know MySQL command or some PHP vars. to do that, if you can help me this will be very appreciated!

Comment: The "command" is called `COUNT()` and is an aggregate MySQL function. Edit: Ah yes, and `SUM()`. my bad ;-)

Comment: It is more likely that the command is `SUM()` in this case.

Comment: Can you give me example? ty

Comment: There all listed here http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx

Comment: @T_D He does NOT need `COUNT()` as we already said.^^

Comment: the meaning of 'I need to have all damage in one' is ambiguous. maybe being more specific in the question (e.g. with an example of the required output, is it 5? or 11708?) would be helpful.

Comment: Output must be all damage counted of all users, or just of one user, if they have multiple rows if you understand me, just type what is easier to you :)

Comment: Make sure that your "Damage" column is indeed an `int` type in order for any aggregate related function to work.

Comment: In your screen capture http://i.imgur.com/TVhwZaE.png, you have `SELECT SUM(dmg)` but your column in your posted code is "Damage", which one is it? Voted to close your question. You need to learn how MySQL works by reading tutorials. We're not a school. Plus,  that's not how you echo a query.

Comment: I gave just an example, this is my real database and row is dmg aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `SUM()` which adds all the rows you specify

```
SELECT SUM(Damage) AS alldamage FROM your_table_name GROUP BY something;
```

Since i don't know the entire table, i can't give you more information, but this is your way to go

Comment: Thats good one, but how i can get this in echo? like i need to echo all value :) thanks

Comment: Basically, you have to execute the query (I don't know what you use, MySQLi, PDO?) which should look like `$alldamage = $db->Execute("SELECT SUM(Damage) AS alldamage FROM your_table_name GROUP BY something;")` Then you just `echo $alldamage` and there you go. Unfortunately, I don't know much about your code and can't give you any further informations unless you provide me with the type of database you're using.

Comment: Then your code should look like this: `$alldamage = $mysqli->query("SELECT SUM(Damage) AS alldamage FROM your_table_name GROUP BY something;");`. The calculated dmg is in `$alldamage` then and you can just echo it

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help, but i get blank page and error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in file.php on line 12, SS of code: http://i.imgur.com/TVhwZaE.png

Comment: @PhihtihPihtih There is a semicolon missing behind the SQL statement above the echo.

Comment: Yeah, how do i miss that.. xD anyway, i got another error here: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in file.php on line 11, SS of code: http://prntscr.com/6wusmm

Comment: @PihtihPihtih Of course, you have to use your database variable, i just used `$mysqli` because I didn't know yours. Replace `$mysqli` with your `$con` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, done that but same error but now in line 12... SS of code: http://prntscr.com/6wuubg i really have no idea

Comment: @PihtihPihtih Oh of course, now i see it. You don't use MySQLi, you use MySQL, that's a difference. Unfortunately, i do not know the syntax of MySQL, but you can google that. Also, i can only recommend you switch to MySQLi or PDO, since MySQL is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all damage values with MySQL, you can use the [SUM function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)

With PHP you can use foreach for each line and count/sum like:

```
...
$count = $count + $result['damage']; // my column from MySQL
...
```

Comment: *"If you want all damage values with MySQL, you can use the SUM function"* - that's a comment which has already been stated in comments.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still, his PHP solution is valid, even tho i would not recommend it for such a task.^^

Comment: @YUNOWORK I didn't say his answer was wrong ;-) an example would have been nice though, rather than a link to.

Answer (score -3):

use `select username AS USERNAME,count(damage) AS ALLDAMAGE from table group by username`

Comment: Count is wrong since he wants the entire damage calculated together, so you need `SUM()`, not `COUNT()`. Also, you can't group it by username since it wouldnt add up everything. And please, always write SQL statements in capital letters.^^

Comment: he has asked counting of rows above & let him decide & comment after getting the solution..